# Modular law and vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a vector space $V,$ with subspaces $A,$ $B,$ $M,$ and $N$ such that $A \cap B = M \cap N$. 
Now the modular law of vector subspaces says that if $O \subset P$ , and $O,$ $P,$ and $J$ are  subspaces of $V,$ then $P \cap (O + J) = O + (P \cap J)$. 
I wish to use this modular law to show that  $(A + (B \cap N)) \cap (A + (B \cap M)) = A $. Here is what I have so far: 
 Since $A \subset A + (B \cap N)) $ then by the modular law, $(A + (B \cap N)) \cap (A + (B \cap M)) = A+((A+B\cap N) \cap (B\cap M)) $.

Edit: Answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last line, it suffices to show
$$(A+(B\cap N)) \cap (B \cap M) \subset A.$$
Anything on the left-hand side can be written as $a+v$ where $a \in A$ and $v \in B \cap N$.

Since $a+v \in B \cap M \subset B$ and $v \in B \cap N \subset B$, we mast have $a \in B$ as well.

So, $a \in A \cap B = M \cap N$ and thus $a+v \in N$. Thus $a+v \in B \cap M \cap N \subset A \cap B \subset A$.

Comment: @JamesDickens $a+v \in B$ and $v \in B$, so $a = (a+v)-v$ must also be in $B$.